# how to access set elements by index like vector?

Tags: c++, stl, set

I have made a code that construct a set of sets. However, I want to access set index like vector *(vec.begin()+i) .Is it possible like accessing vector? I got an error,Please help me, Is there any solution

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int myints[] = {75,23,65,42,13};
  std::set<int> myset (myints,myints+5);

  std::cout << "myset contains:";
  for (int i = 0; i < myset.size(); i++) {
      cout<<*(myset.begin()+i);
  }


  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, it's not possible. Despite the C++ implementation of sets being ordered, a set is not a sequence. You can iterate from `begin()`, though.

Comment: You can make a "shadow vector" of `vector<int*>` (or `vector<set<int>::iterator>`) which points to each item in the set.  The shadow vector is invalidated whenever the set changes, and must be reconstructed as a cache of pointers to the set items.  Kate Gregory has said that you should carefully weigh the pros and cons of each container type, and then and only then you should always select `std::vector`.

Comment: In this case it will be possible to iterate directly over the set with `for (auto x : myset) cout << x;`

Answer (score 1):

You can with [`std::next`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next). But it's not a good idea for `std::set` because it must linearly increment the iterator.

```
auto third = std::next(myset.begin(), 2);
```